# AES библиотека на чистом C++

Tags: c++, aes

Привет, господа не подкинете библиотеку на чистом С++? В сети лежат только заточеные под платформу AVR. Спасибо.

Comment: OpenSSL посмотрите. Там, насколько я помню, не особо сложно выдирается алгоритм.

Answer (score 2):

А чем вас не устраивает вот этот вариант?
[Crypto++® Library 5.6.2](http://www.cryptopp.com/)